# Trouble writing into shared memory buffer in C

Tags: c, memory, shared

Let's say i have a buffer:

```
int * buffer;
```

and this buffer is shared with multiple processes (shared memory).

If i want to read/write from/to that buffer how would i do it?

I'm asking this because i found lot's of information and all sorts of different methods to solve this problem, but the answers lacked organisation, and became very confusing and difficult to understand.

Here's the function i used to create the shared memory segment:

```
void * create_shared_memory(char *name, int size) {

    int *ptr;
    int ret;

    int fd = shm_open (name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    if (fd == -1) { 
        perror ("shm_open error!");
        exit (1);
    }

    ret = ftruncate (fd, sizeof (size));

    if (ret == -1) {
         perror ("ftruncate error!");
         exit (2);
    }

    ptr = mmap(0, sizeof (size), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,  MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror ("shm-mmap error!");
        exit (3);
    }

return ptr;

}
```

Comment: How is the memory being shared? Are you using `pthread`, OpenMP, or something else? Or do you mean the memory needs to be shared across codes?

Comment: What's the issue? Once you've used `mmap` you can access the memory as you would normally.

Comment: the issue is that i want to do it in different functions. One for creating the shared memory segment, other to read from it, and other to write to it. @teppic

Comment: If you both write and read from shared memory, you need synchronization, locks, atomics, what have you.

Comment: i have all that but since this is a large project, i just want a generic answer so i can understand how to do this @EOF

Comment: So you have "all that", and the one thing you post is the *allocation* of the shared memory? Why?

Comment: The problem is the same with memory shared between processes as with memory shared between threads, and there is no generic answer. How you code and synchronize your reads and writes depends on what you store in the memory, and how you need to access it. Try asking about the algorithm or data structure you're trying to implement, since this question only discusses the bit you already have working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having created and mapped a shared memory segment, thereby obtaining a pointer to it, you read from or write to it via that pointer.  As far as syntax and mechanics, this is the same as for any other memory.  You can wrap functions around that any way you like, but you do not inherently need to do so.

As EOF observed, however, shared memory *semantics* are a lot more complicated than non-shared memory semantics.  You need to use appropriate synchronization aids around shared-memory accesses to ensure that threads and/or processes cooperate properly, else the results are undefined.